Proof of non-existence of a descending sequence of sets: what if there is no function corresponding to sequence.
The beginning of the proof that no infinite descending sequence of sets exists from Wikipedia:
Suppose, to the contrary, that there is a function $f$ on the natural numbers such that $f(n+1) \in f(n)$ for each $n$. Define $S = \{f(n) : n \text{ is a natural number}\}$, the range of $f$, which can be seen as a set according to the axiom schema of replacement.
Regarding the axiom of replacement, it is stated that the schema applies only to definable surjections, which are identified by their defining formulas.
What if the sequence exists, but there is no corresponding function defined by a formula?

Why does a function need to be defined by a formula? Can't we talk about e.g. the functions obtained from axiom of choice, and apply this schema too?

If $f$ is a set function, then its definable according to wikipedia's definition for we can define $F(x) = y$ as $f(x) = y$ i.e. $(x, y)\in \text{graph}(f)$

@Jakobian The what does this mean: "the schema applies only to definable surjections, which are identified by their defining formulas"?

Link the page with the proof, please.

A set function is basically a set $\text{graph}(f)$ consisting of ordered pairs such that if $(x, y)$ and $(x, z)$ belong to it then $y = z$. Any function can be considered as a class function $F_P$ where $P(x, y)$ is defined to be $(x, y)\in\text{graph}(f)$. The comment about surjections on wikipedia is weird to me too, since any function is a surjection onto its image and that axiom schema of replacement doesn't actually talk about any concept of "surjective". Just that image of a set is a set.

The axiom schema allows parameters.

Then if we defined $F_P$ that way, then the axiom schema of replacement says that if $A$ is a set, then $F_P[A] = f[A] = {f(x) : x\in A}$ is a set. So in fact, if we are dealing with set functions, and in this context this is certainly what wikipedia is talking about, then everything makes sense, where $A = \mathbb{N}$.

@spaceisdarkgreen
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists
also I cited https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement

@Jakobian
f is definable if and only if the graph of f (i.e., { (x, y) : f(x) = y }) is a definable set. Definable set is an n-ary relation on the domain of a structure whose elements satisfy some formula in the first-order language of that structure.

As Andrés remarks in the comments, "definable" in the axiom of replacement means definable with (set) parameters, so if $f$ is a set, it is a definable function in this sense, so amenable to replacement, as Jakobian indicates. We can also avoid the axiom of replacement entirely for the purpose of constructing the range of a set-function, by using separation and union to define $\operatorname{ran}(f) = \{y\in \bigcup\bigcup f: \exists x\;(x,y)\in f\}.$
Going beyond sets, the axiom of replacement has us covered by the same argument for definable classes (identified, as you say, by their defining formula). Note, though, that since we need $\omega$ to be a set in order to use replacement, the axiom of infinity also plays a crucial role. In fact, if it doesn't hold, then it is possible for there to be definable infinite descending class-sequences even in the presence of the foundation axiom, and a stronger foundation schema, saying that every definable class has an $\in$-minimal element, is required to rule them out.
Definable classes are the only things that can be rightfully called "classes" in a ZFC context, but this doesn't preclude non-well-founded models of ZFC, where there are infinite descending sequences that are not definable in the model. Note Wikipedia has remarks on this in the paragraph beneath the quoted passage.
In class-set theories like NBG or Morse-Kelley, replacement is given as a single axiom quantifying over all class functions with set domains, so we can actually prove a sentence that there are no infinite decreasing class-sequences of sets. But this doesn't preclude non-well-founded models either, since not every subset of the model's universe need be a class in the model (the semantics of these theories are generally taken as first-order).

So it's possible to show that $f$ is a set in any (or some) well-founded model of ZFC?

@JuljaMuvv Not sure I understand what you're asking. What kind of thing, a priori, is $f$ here?

It seems to me that $f$ is a priori a collection of pairs $(i, a_i)$, $i\in \mathbb{N}$, which is not necessary a set.

So I still don't understand why this proof is valid.

@JuljaMuvv I would interpret the proof as being about a set. This is what would usually be meant by saying “we can prove there is no infinite descending sequence”.

@JuljaMuvv (Though if I were writing it I would avoid citing replacement as it is typically used for proving definable mappings  that are not sets a priori are sets.)

So, ''there is no infinite descending sequence in model" is a weaker statement than ''the model is well-founded"?

@Julja yes. An ill-founded model may satisfy the axiom of foundation. There is no first-order condition that, if satisfied, ensures a model to be well-founded.
